# Is it possible to use SPDY module for non-secure connections?

Tags: http, https, connection, spdy

SPDY module is designed to only work with secure connections (SSL-enabled websites).
I want to know there is any fork of that project (specifically MOD_SPDY for apache) which bypasses SSL and works over non-secure HTTP (and not HTTPS) connections?
If no, is it possible to modify and rebuild the source (easily!) for that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely, since the protocol specifies transport security, even if you could gut `mod_spdy` to not need it, no client is going to make a connection without TLS anyway.